# Can't access remote folders in Music / Photo

Tags: music, samba

All my music and my photos are on a NAS. Those folders are shared via Samba.

It seems it's impossible to access samba shares when defining the library location for my music or photos.

I tried "enter a location" , then typed "smb://myNasName" or "smb://myNasIP" but nothing happens when I click "open".
Obvisouly I can access and browse those shares using the file manager using the same path.

Anyway I just discovered Elementary OS, and it looks really great !

Answer (score 1):

You could mount these shares permanently to local folders:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently